# Incrementing ID with DA Update Cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, attributeerror

I'm currently applying a select by attribute query to select null values before applying an increment cursor, but I'm interested in reducing the code by using a where clause and employing the updated da module. Current code:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management (fc, "fc_update")
gisID = "GIS_2016_0"
where_clause = 'GIS_2016_0 IS NULL'
MaxValue = 1000

def autoIncrement (start=0, step=1):
    i = start
    while 1:
         yield i
         i+=step 

nextValue = MaxValue + 2
incrementer = autoIncrement (nextValue, 2)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("fc_update", gisID, where_clause) as incrementCursor:
print "Populating fields with no IDs"
    for row in incrementCursor:
        row.setValue(gisID, incrementer.next())
        incrementCursor.updateRow(row)
    del row, incrementCursor
    print "Finished populating null fields"
```

I get the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'setValue'

I'm not certain about how to adapt the increment statements to accommodate a da update cursor, or if my where_clause statement even works.

Comment: You are confusing ArcPy.da cursor syntax with ArcPy cursor syntax so I would recommend reviewing the samples in the documentation of the former.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing syntax between [`arcpy.UpdateCursor()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/updatecursor.htm) and [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).  As @PolyGeo recommends, you should read up on the documentation for [`arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).

```
print "Populating fields with no IDs"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor ("fc_update", gisID, where_clause) as incrementCursor:
    for row in incrementCursor:
        row[0] = incrementer.next()
        incrementCursor.updateRow(row)
print "Finished populating null fields"
```

Comment: Great, thank you this worked, and your explanation makes sense

Comment: @saoirse If this has worked for you please consider voting and accepting. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)